# RequireJS and Mocha

Tags: javascript, testing, dependencies, requirejs, mocha.js

I have a web app using RequireJS. Here is my `js/main.js` file:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery',
        lodash: 'libs/lodash/lodash',
        backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone',
        // [other dependencies...]
    }
});

require(['views/AppView'], function (AppView) {
    var app_view = new AppView;
});
```

here is my `js/views/AppView.js` file:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'joint',
    'views/ProjectView',
    'models/Command',
    'views/detailsview',
    'views/newcellview'
], function ($, _, Backbone, joint, ProjectView, Command, DetailsView, NewCellView) {
    var app_view = {stub: 'stub'};
    return app_view;
});
```

and finally here is my `AppViewTest.js` file which I run with `mocha js/test/AppViewTest.js`:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

describe('AppView', function() {
    var app_view;
    beforeEach(function (done) {
        requirejs(['../views/AppView.js'], function (AppView) {
            app_view = new AppView;
        });
    });
    it('should be [...]', function() {
        assert.equal(app_view, ...);
    });
});
```

I get the following error:

```
1) AppView views "before each" hook:
   Uncaught Tried loading "jquery" at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/jquery.js then tried node's require("jquery") and it failed with error: Error: Cannot find module 'jquery'
```

Comment: I've edited your question to remove information that is no longer relevant and just keep what matters to your current problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start your test with:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var requirejs = require('requirejs');
```

and then you start making calls to `requirejs` but there's nothing in here that configures RequireJS.

If you cut and paste the `require.config` call you have in your `main.js` into your test file, that would configure your test for loading the same files as you have in your regular application.

Another way to do it would be:

```
before(function (done) {
    requirejs(['full-path-to/main'], function () {
        requirejs(['../views/AppView'], function (AppView) {
            app_view = new AppView;
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

The point is to load your configuration before you load your `AppView`. Note also that you need to call `done`, and I've changed `beforeEach` to `before` because there's no need to reload it before each test. (It was a slip of the mind earlier when I induced you to use `beforeEach`. My bad.)

I've also removed the `.js` from your `requirejs` call because you should not use `.js`. Sometimes it is warranted but unless you can explain *why* you need it, you should not use it.

Comment: This probably solves the problem. Actually, I still get an error, but this time it seems related _specifically_ to JQuery: `Uncaught Error: Evaluating ./libs/jquery/jquery.js as module "jquery" failed with error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined`

Comment: Yes, for many purposes jQuery needs to have a DOM environment to run. There are tons of questions in the Mocha tag that deal with providing a DOM to jQuery during testing.

Comment: I get it: `createDocument()` is a DOM method, and I'm using Node so maybe I have to create a stub for the `document` DOM element.

Comment: Great, so thanks for all the help. I think that this actually solves the problem, so I will accept your answer.